# Problem with reciving information from GPS on Android

Tags: android

I just started playing with android device and have problem with getting updates from GPS listener.

Firstly, the code, so You could check if I'm doing everything right:

In AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
```

Location listener is defined as private member of Activity:

```
private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location pLocation) {
        double lLatitude = pLocation.getLatitude();
        double lLongitude = pLocation.getLongitude();
        mGpsTextView.setText ("Longitude" + Double.toString(lLongitude) + " Latitude: " + Double.toString(lLatitude));
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        mGpsTextView.setText ("Provider disabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        mGpsTextView.setText ("Provider enabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status)
        {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            mGpsTextView.setText("GPS out of service");
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            mGpsTextView.setText("GPS temorarily unawalible");
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            mGpsTextView.setText("GPS avalible");
            break;
        default:
            mGpsTextView.setText("GPS crazy");
        }

   }

};
```

In "onResume" method I aquire LocationManager and register my listener:

```
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0.0f, mLocationListener);
```

In "onPause" I remove listener

```
    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
```

Then, when I test the code on emulator with geo fix - everything works perfect. But when I deploy my app on phone the code not work as it should. When the provider is disabled the text on the "mGpsTextView" is "provider disabled" - so it is ok. But when I run app with gps provider enabled the text on "mGpsTextView" and no updates are recived (checked it with debugger - onLocationChanges isn't called).

Any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Did you paste the wrong bit of code here? You don't seem to give your LocationListener anywhere.

Comment: yes, I just copy-pasted wrong code

Comment: ph, the question can be closed - I just left device for 30 min and it started reciving updates. The magic of cheap phone... Sory for trouble;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - using LocationManager does not give a geo fix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938719/android-using-locationmanager-does-not-give-a-geo-fix)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER?

It should be something like this:

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 100.0f, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 60000, 0.0f, locationListener);
```